# Having trouble with understanding proof of the sequential criterion for functional limits

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, sequences-and-series, epsilon-delta

I found this proof of the sequential criterion online:
[image]

And I understand everything up to the second part where they prove that the convergence of the sequences implies the convergence of the function.

I understand their logical arguments yet I'm having trouble understanding how they proved that their $\{x_n\}$ sequence converges to $c$ because $\forall n \in \mathbb{N}: \; 0 < \vert x_n - c \vert < \frac{1}{n}$ but this doesn't necessarily mean that $\forall \varepsilon > 0$ the condition for convergence holds, only for $\varepsilon$ of the form $\frac{1}{n}$.

Is what I'm saying wrong? Can anyone please explain to me how I might prove that $\displaystyle\lim_{n \to \infty} x_n = c$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assume you have the condition for every $n$, and take $\varepsilon>0$. By the Archimedean Principle, there exists $n_0\in\mathbb N$ with $\tfrac1{n_0}<\varepsilon$. So if $|x_n-c|<\tfrac1n$ for all $n$, for any $n<n_0$ you have $\tfrac1n<\tfrac1{n_0}<\varepsilon$. Thus $x_n\to c$.

Note that it looks that you are getting confused by the presence of $\varepsilon$ in the definition of limit. That "$x_n\to c$" should mean that as $n$ grows, $x_n$ should be closer and closer to $c$. And that's definitely guaranteed if the distance between $x_n$ and $c$ is less than $\tfrac1n$.

Comment: Why did you write $x_n \to 0$? Shouldn't $x_n \to c$?

Comment: Yep. $\ \ \ \ \ $

Comment: Ok, so the gist is pretty much $\forall \varepsilon > 0 \exists n \in \mathbb{N}: \frac{1}{n} < \varepsilon \Rightarrow \forall k \in \mathbb{N} \vert x_k - c \vert < \frac{1}{n} < \varepsilon \Rightarrow \displaystyle \lim_{n \to \infty} x_n = c$ am I correct?

Comment: No. The assertion $\lim_nx_n=c$ means that, for every $\varepsilon>0$, there exists $n_0$ such that for all $n>n_0$, you have $|x_n-c|<\varepsilon$.

Comment: $\displaystyle\forall \varepsilon > 0: \exists n_0 \in \mathbb{N}: \exists k \in \mathbb{N}: \frac{1}{k} < \varepsilon \Rightarrow \forall n > n_0: \vert x_n - c \vert < \frac{1}{k} < \varepsilon \Rightarrow \lim_{n \to \infty} x_n = c$. Is this correct?

Comment: That's painful to read, but it looks like it it correct.

Comment: Ok, thanks so much, I know I'm being annoying It's just important for me to prove everything in formal writing. Thanks for your help!

Comment: That's fine. Just don't abuse symbols, they make everything harder to read. The only time when it's worth to write the definition of limit in symbols, is when you want to write its negation.

Comment: And please consider upvoting and accepting answers, as that's how this site works.

Comment: Just did, I'm kind of a newbie here :) Again, thanks for your help

Comment: No problem, and I know you are new, that's why I mentioned it. I hope you stay.